# Get absolute URL in Play framework and Secure social

Tags: java, http, playframework-2.0, absolute-path, securesocial

I'm using secure social in my Play project. I'm trying to use my own E-Mail for the registaiton process.

The how to is described here:

> http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html

My Problem is, that I get an error when I try to genreate the absoute URL in the template:

> @securesocial.controllers.routes.Registration.signUp(mailToken).absoluteURL(IdentityProvider.sslEnabled)

Here ist the Error Log:

> [error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error:
>   java.lang.Runt imeException: There is no HTTP Context available from
>   here. [error] application -
>
> ! @6j0al12dk - Internal server error, for (POST) [/signup] ->
>
> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException:
>   There is no  HTTP Context available from here.]]
>           at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_
>   2.10.jar:2.2.3]
>           at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_
>   2.10.jar:2.2.3]
>           at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun
>   $applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
>
> ```
>     at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun
> ```
>
> $applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
>
> ```
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
>     at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrE
> ```
>
> lse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3] Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available
>   from h ere.
>           at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:30) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
>           at play.mvc.Http$Context$Implicit.ctx(Http.java:196) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2 .3]
>           at play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$.requestHeader(TemplateMagicForJava.scal
>   a:56) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
>           at views.html.custom.mails.signUpEmail$.apply(signUpEmail.template.scala
>   :42) ~[classes/:na]
>           at plugins.NekViews.getSignUpEmail(NekViews.scala:100) ~[classes/:na]
>           at securesocial.core.providers.utils.Mailer$.sendSignUpEmail(Mailer.scal
>   a:49) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3] [info] application -
>   [securesocial] unloaded identity provider: userpass [info] application
>   - [securesocial] unloaded password hasher bcrypt [info] play - Shutdown application 
>   default Akka system.

Does anybody know what the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Your template requires implicit request which is mandatory for obtaining an absolute URL.

```
@(/*template's parameters*/)(implicit request: RequestHeader)
```

This request must be available in a method which renders the template.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty similar error if not the same, probably you're also mixing some java code in your project.

You must create a java context in your controller ( in this case the custom views controller ) for it to be used by the views.

**For example:**

Scala helper to create a java context

```
object JavaContext {

  import play.mvc.Http
  import play.core.j.JavaHelpers

  def withContext[Status](block: => Status)(implicit header: RequestHeader): Status = {
    try {
      Http.Context.current.set(JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(header))
      block
    }
    finally {
      Http.Context.current.remove()
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class CustomSecureSocialTemplates(env:RuntimeEnvironment[_]) extends ViewTemplates.Default(env:RuntimeEnvironment[_])
{

  override def getLoginPage(form: Form[(String, String)],
                            msg: Option[String] = None)(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang): Html = {
    JavaContext.withContext {
      views.html.security.login(form,msg)
    }
  }

//...
}
```

Source: [dominikdorn.com](http://dominikdorn.com/2014/08/play-framework-java-scala-in-one-project-no-http-context-available/)